# Can the class display in textfield?

Tags: java

In my case,type 'xml2.xml3(4);' in other class.The result was displayed in console.

Can the result displayed in text field?

```
public class xml2 {    
    public static void  xml3(int index) {        
        try {
            File fXmlFile = new File("AST10106_ProjectSampleData.xml");
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);

            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

            NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("record");
            Node nNode = nList.item(index);
            Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
            System.out.println("Record : " + eElement.getAttribute("record"));
            System.out.println("Brand : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("Brand").item(0).getTextContent());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }        
    }    
}
```

Comment: Well yes, you can convert the result of a method into a string, and set that as the text in a text field... but you'd want `xml3` to *return* the data rather than printing it out. I'd also strongly recommend that you start following Java naming conventions and give your classes and methods meaningful names.

Comment: Yes there are many ways to go about doing this. You could create a static method in your class that contains the TextField, which would have to be an instance variable, and it could look something like `public static void setTextFieldText( String text )` that just sets the text of the TextField with whatever you pass in. This is just one example.